# Appropriate datastructure for overwriting and efficient ordering

Tags: algorithm, rust

Simplified, I have a struct `Packet{messge:string, timestamp:int}` and I am putting packets into a `BTreeSet` ordered by timestamp. I need a `BTreeset` because I need to know the packets with min/max timestamp at any given point.

If two packets with the same message with different timestamps are sent, I want to overwrite the old packet with the new packet.
Example:

- At time T I get packet with {"foo", T}
- At T+100, I get packet with {"foo", T+100}

I want my datastructure to implicitly discard the older packet.

```rust
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::collections::BTreeSet;
use std::collections::BinaryHeap;
use std::time::Duration;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Packet {
    timestamp: usize,
    message: String,
}

impl Ord for Packet {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Packet) -> Ordering {
        return self.timestamp.cmp(&other.timestamp).reverse();
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for Packet {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Packet) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl Eq for Packet {}

impl PartialEq for Packet {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Packet) -> bool {
        return self.message == other.message;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p1 = Packet {
        timestamp: 1,
        message: "foo".to_string(),
    };
    let p2 = Packet {
        timestamp: 2,
        message: "foo".to_string(),
    };

    let mut set = BTreeSet::new();
    set.insert(p1);
    set.insert(p2);

    // Expected: should just print the second packet
    for p in set.iter() {
        dbg!(p);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8491eb8f39217b256d77a7f5bea6fd56)

As you can see, I want the new packet to overwrrite the older packet from the datastructure, but that's not happening (both are getting included)

I guess I could use multiple datastructures (maybe with another hashset),  but I'd like to model the dataclass (Packet) so that it plays nicely with just one data structure.

Is `BTreeSet` the right fit here? Or am I implementing Eq/Ord incorrectly? What would be the best Rust data structure for my usecase?

Comment: Do you want min/max by what?

Comment: **You cannot** provide different `PartialOrd` and `PartialEq`. They have to compare exactly the same.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman by timestamp

Comment: Why not just separately keep track of the packet(s) with the oldest and newest timestamp at each point, and maintain a set/map to store the latest packet for each message type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 3rd party priority-queue with add/remomve

https://crates.io/crates/priority-queue

```
xtern crate priority_queue; // not necessary in Rust edition 2018

use priority_queue::PriorityQueue;

fn main() {
    let mut pq = PriorityQueue::new();

    assert!(pq.is_empty());
    pq.push("Apples", 5);
    pq.push("Bananas", 8);
    pq.push("Strawberries", 23);

    assert_eq!(pq.peek(), Some((&"Strawberries", &23)));

    for (item, _) in pq.into_sorted_iter() {
        println!("{}", item);
    }
}
```